# multiply index value and column

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following df :

```
          A     B       C
A         A    A*B     A*C
B        A*B    B      B*C
C        A*C    B*C      C
```

I have on ther side a dfs with the values:

```
df0:  
A*B   3  
A*C   4
B*C   2

df1:
A     2 
B     8
C     3
```

Is there anyway I can substitute the values of the dataframe by the corresponding numerical values?

Comment: Is the first dataframe filled with strings?

Comment: if you refer to the one that multiplies the indices letters by the column headers yes is filled with strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seeems you need [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html):

```
print (df0)
     a
A*B  3
A*C  4
B*C  2
print (df1)
   b
A  2
B  8
C  3

df1 = df.replace(df0['a']).replace(df1['b'])
print (df1)
   A  B  C
A  2  3  4
B  3  8  2
C  4  2  3
```